# Use system default icons in Tkinter and Python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to use the systems default icons for known task (copy, cut, paste, filenew, fileopen, exit, help, ...). This depends on the current used icon set in the desktop environment and/or on the used operating system.

Does Python offer a plattform independed way to get such icons?

Here is some Tkinter-based pseudocode

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import *

root = Tk()

image = image.open(DEFAULT_COPY_ICON)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

button = Button(master=root, text='Copy', image=image))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `PyGTK` has names for system icons but probably only for Linux. But `PyGTK` is not `Tkinter`.

Comment: Could you provide the system default icon for any of those tasks? I question their very existance for Windows for example.

Comment: I am not sure it can even be done for Linux only. Icon themes come with different formats (svg, png, ...) and different folder organizations. In addition, I think that the way to find the current theme depend on the desktop environment.

Comment: @Nae MSDN lists a couple of windows defaults [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760433(v=vs.85).aspx).
Edit: Usage [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298381(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python3 or Tkinter does not offer a way for this.